# How can I set a default value for date field using hook_form_alter

Tags: forms

I am new to Drupal. I need to set a default value to a date field. Please anyone help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below code to set a default value for date field using hook_form_alter

```
$form["your_date_field"]["und"][0]['#default_value']['value'] = '2016-11-16 00:00:00';
```